# Yii2 Слушатель на обновление

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть проект на yii2. Он пишет определенные логи при изменении статуса в catalogOrder, выгдялит это таким образом.

bootstrap.php

```
\yii\base\Event::on(
    \ms\loyalty\catalog\common\models\CatalogOrder::class,
    \ms\loyalty\catalog\common\models\CatalogOrder::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE,
    [\common\listeners\CatalogOrderListener::class, 'catalogOrderOnChangeStatus']
);

\yii\base\Event::on(
    \ms\loyalty\catalog\common\models\CatalogOrder::class,
    \ms\loyalty\catalog\common\models\CatalogOrder::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT,
    [\common\listeners\CatalogOrderListener::class, 'catalogOrderOnChangeStatus']
);
```

Ну и сам код:

```
public static function catalogOrderOnChangeStatus(Event $event)
{
    try {
        /** @var CatalogOrder $catalogOrder */
        $catalogOrder = $event->sender;

        if ($event instanceof AfterSaveEvent || $catalogOrder->isAttributeChanged('status')) {
            (new CreateExtranetLog())->handle('order_id', $catalogOrder->id, self::EXTERNAL_LOG_URL);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Самое интересное, что когда срабатывает 'добавление' он отрабатывает корректно, но когда срабатывает 'обновление', этого не происходит. Подскажите куда копать??

Comment: Добавить больше логов, очевидно. Убедиться что происходит именно `AfterSaveEvent`, что меняется атрибут `status`, что не выпадает эксепшен.

Comment: @u_mulder Я пробовал они не пишутся. Хотя везде всё прописано. Такое ощущение, что на update он просто не вызывается.

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться отладкой и не посмотреть все значения в событии и вообще в стеке?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Каким образом ?

Comment: Я же написал: отладка О_о   ....  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482

Comment: Интересно, а почему выбрали такое решение? Ведь можно в модели CatalogOrder использовать afterSave, где можно делать тоже самое и без проблем)

Comment: @Евгений Ну это было не моё решение, это было уже написано. Я просто пытался найти проблему. И кажется нашел. Потому что проблема была в том, в определенный момент менялся определенный параметр и это был не статус. Поэтому логи не срабатывали.